# Facebook API - How to access video insights on period prior to that of extraction?

Tags: python, facebook, video

I'm working on Facebook Graph API, to extract video insights (page_video_views) on a daily basis. 
It appears that the API will only return the video views of the day that the extract is run. 
For instance, if I'm running the extract on the views of a specific video on February 1st, it will return the total views that video had made until February 1st. 
I couldn't request on February 1st the total video views a video has made on January 1st.

Has anyone already encountered this problem ?
Have you managed to solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which `period` did you use?